# How to combine autosizing and stretching for child controls?

Tags: wpf

I need to implement the following scenario:

First, parent control (window) is autosized to fit its content.
But if Width or Height exceed some value autosize mode is switched off and then follows manual resizing with child controls stretching to occupy available space.

Consider `Grid` inside `Window`:

```
<Window>
     <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here I need the middle row to be adaptive changing from "Auto" to "*".
Is it possible without much magic?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Window.MaxHeight` and `Window.MaxWidth` properties without setting any `Window.Height` or `Window.Width` properties.

Comment: This doesn't help. The problem is not in Window itself but in the grid. It can either stretch and adjust the size to the parent or expand as its children require. May be triggers can help.